# pgfgantt - adjust vgrid with \gantttitlecalendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I am using `\gantttitlecalendar` to generate my title block that consists of months and weeks.

The default behaviour of `vgrid` is to take each unit as a day, or if `compress calendar` is true, each unit is taken as a month.

I would like to have vertical grid lines to demarcate each week.

This is what I currently have

```
 % Minimal
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\ganttset{calendar week text= \small {\startday/\startmonth}}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    hgrid,x unit=1.5mm,
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid,
    time slot format=little-endian]{22-09-2014}{30-11-2014}
\gantttitlecalendar{ month=shortname,week=4} \\
\ganttgroup{Group A}{22-09-14}{28-11-14}\\
\ganttbar{Task A}{22-09-14}{10-11-14}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me
[image: Minimal example - vgird = days]

How would one adjust the `vgrid` for weeks?

Comment: Can you change your example to something that compiles (it has errors now) and produces the same result as the image you show? I've spent 20 minutes messing with your code and I can't get to the same starting point shown in the image?

Comment: Sorry Paul, I seem to have missed the following line `time slot format=little-endian]{22-09-2014}{30-11-2014}` have updated my code, should compile now to get to the same image I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `<style list>` value for the `vgrid` key to draw a grid line only once per week, like this:

```
vgrid={*{6}{draw=none},dotted},
```

The `<style list>` is cycled through as we move left to right through the Gantt chart, and the `*{<num>}{<style>}` works just like in `tabular` preambles for repeating elements. So the line of code above makes the first 6 grid lines with style `draw=none` (so not visible at all) and the seventh is `dotted` style. This repeats, so it achieves the goal of one grid line per week.

Here's the full code and output:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\ganttset{calendar week text= \small {\startday/\startmonth}}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  hgrid,x unit=1.5mm,
  hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
  vgrid={*{6}{draw=none},dotted},
  time slot format=little-endian,
]{22-09-2014}{30-11-2014}
  \gantttitlecalendar{ month=shortname,week=4} \\
  \ganttgroup{Group A}{22-09-14}{28-11-14}\\
  \ganttbar{Task A}{22-09-14}{10-11-14}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I assumed you wanted the grid line to correspond to the week markers in the title block section, but if you want the line on a different day of the week, you can adjust the `<style list>` to include the required offset.