# LaTex: Possibility to use vgrid offset in pgfgantt?

Tags: pgfgantt

### Problem Description

I have an offset problem with vgrid in pgfgantt.

I would like to have a gridline for every week.

If I start the week with a first day of a week (monday, the last day in June) I get also the cut title of June which I do not want to have there but then the vgrid is correctly adjusted to the weeks.
If I start with the 1st of August my vgrid needs to have one day offset.

I have googled now two hours and have not found any real solution.

I could write a long style list for vgrid, but this list would be very long, because I would need to write it for 5 years as a non repeating list.

Basically I have the same situation as in this thread, just that I need the in the answer  mentioned but not explained offset:
[Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236948/pgfgantt-adjust-vgrid-with-gantttitlecalendar)

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfgantt} %Für Gantt-Chart
\ganttset{calendar week text={\currentweek}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=little-endian, x unit=0.06cm,y unit title = 0.8cm, y unit chart = 0.8cm, vgrid={*6{draw=none}, dotted} ]{31.07.17}{31.08.18}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week}{}\ganttnewline
\ganttgroup[progress=0]{Element 1}{01.08.17}{31.08.18} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{01.08.17}{01.09.17}\\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{01.08.17}{01.10.17}

 \end{ganttchart}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Five years later running into the same issue, here is how I achieved the desired Weekly Gantt chart:

1. `vgrid` can accept a *list* of styles that take repetition markers, which then gets applied in order, circling around to the beginning and repeating until the end of the chart's period. In particular, the syntax looks like this

```
vgrid={*{<n>}{<style>}, *{<n>}{<style>}, ...}
```

where `n` is the repetition count for the corresponding `style`. In particular, if `off` is the desired offset, then the following achieves what we want:

```
vgrid={*{off}{draw=none}, <style>, *{<6-off>}{draw=none}}
```

which should define a list of exactly 7 styles, with `style` sitting at the monday position. Note, however, that the `6-off` arithmetic cannot be performed directly in the brackets, so for a one-off solution, you can simply hard code the value.

2. Leverage the [datetime2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) package to automatically calculate the offset.

```
\usepackage{datetime2,datetime2-calc}
...
\DTMcomputedayofweekindex{<starting date>}{\startdow}
\newcount\off\off\startdow\multiply\off -1\advance\off 6 % \off == 6-\startdow
```

which puts the numeric Day of the Week of `<starting date>` into `startdow` and uses that value to calculate the offset in `off`.

3. Use `\ganttset` to set `vgrid` from the above variables.

Unfortunately, `\off` and `\startdow` won't expand if supplied directly within the optional argument of `\begin{ganttchart}[...]`, but we can programmatically set the property with `ganttset`:

```
\ganttset{vgrid={*{\the\off}{draw=none}, dotted, *{\startdow}{draw=none}}
```

However, there's a gotcha. It turns out that a repetition count of `0` doesn't work as expected, so so we have to handle the cases where `\startdow` or `\off` are `0` separately. In particular,

4. I have the above wrapped up in a macro:

```
\def\gantchartweekly#1#2{
  \DTMcomputedayofweekindex{#1}{\startdow}
  \newcount\off\off\startdow\multiply\off -1\advance\off 6

  \begin{ganttchart}[<formatting>]{#1}{#2}
    \ifnum\off=0
      \ganttset{vgrid={dotted, *{\the\off}{draw=none}}}
    \else\if\startdow=0
      \ganttset{vgrid={*{\startdow}{draw=none}, dotted}}
    \else
      \ganttset{vgrid={*{\the\off}{draw=none}, dotted, *{\startdow}{draw=none}}}
    \fi\fi
    \gantttitlecalendar{year,month,week}
}
```